# What is the purpose of the char datatype?

Tags: java, string, char

I am currently reading a textbook on Java and each chapter involving the `String` datatype also discusses `char`. My question is, what purpose does `char` have in the real world?

The only thing I have found is that because `String` is immutable, it makes it a poor choice for passwords. Thus, one should choose a character array (`char[]`) over `String`. However, Java does have a mutable class for strings called `StringBuilder`; would that not be just as suitable a replacement for strings as is `char[]`?

Comment: `char` is meant to hold 2 bytes.

Comment: To store characters?

Comment: There are many, many, many uses. But, if you want a simple one, how could you iterate (loop) over the characters that make up a string if you didn't have a datatype to represent individual characters?

Comment: It represents a UTF16 character.

Comment: To [make a `String` work](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java/#114)? You can't make a class representing a sequence of characters if you don't have a way to represent an individual character, now can you?

Comment: A `char[]` is safer than a `String` because array entries can be overwritten while a `String` is stored in the stringpool (leaving aside whether or not it's still important once the attacker has access to your JVM instance). It has nothing to do with the reason a `char` exists though.

Comment: Consider:  How would you ask "is the 7th character in this String a 'V'?" if you could not somehow extract the 7th character as an individual entity?

Comment: @HotLicks: JavaScript doesn't have chars, and it's still possible to do it :-).

Comment: @JBNizet - Awkwardly, I'm sure.

Comment: As almost everything in JavaScript :-). But if you think about it, a char is nothing but a string of one character. That's how you do in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been answered in the comments really :)

A `String` is a collection of `Char`s. Without `Char`s you would have nothing to build `String`s from.

Because `Char[]` and dealing with `Char[]` is so important they warrant having their own class to handle the processing of them - hence `String`.

In your coding you are unlikely to use the `Char` datatype directly unless you are processing `String`s or handling passwords. The only reason `Char[]` is used for passwords is because it's harder to accidentally print them into logs/view them in memory/put them into string caches, etc and because once you have finished with it you can explicitly zero the elements in the Array so it never stays in memory longer than needed.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know enough about Java yet to understand how the java.lang package works at a fundamental level, and I was certain this was going to come off as a horrendously stupid question. I am glad to have received a non-sarcastic response. :-)

Comment: @MatthewHolmes Sarcastic is fun, you need not get repelled by sarcastic answers :) Laugh at them